# rust iterator::any only accepts function which FnMut signature?

Tags: rust, closures

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/closures/closure_examples/iter_any.html

Rust book mentions iterator::any as an example of closures and iterator::any takes function as an argument with FnMut condition imposed. Based on my understanding, FnMut should not consume the value but only mutably borrow it. Consume is only allowed through FnOnce. So I thought following code would not compile because drop(x) clearly consumes x, but it compiled so i'm confused whether drop(x) doesn't consume value x or function input parameter can changed through compiler.

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];

array1.iter().any(|&x| {
            drop(x);
            return true;
        })
```

Comment: To force a `FnOnce` closure, you need to capture something by value and consume it in the closure, e.g. [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dca74a3222b386c94c5c87bc9d7c2b0c). Passing the closure [directly](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f3535b3b0de0bef5e2e859ca15d354d9) to `any()` will force it to be `FnMut` and you'll get a different error, about not being able to move out of a capture in a `FnMut` closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few misconceptions to unpack here.

1. The closure traits `FnMut`, `Fn` and `FnOnce` can all receive their arguments by reference or by value. The closure type is orthogonal to how the arguments are passed. A function that consumes its argument can be called many times, and it will consume its argument each time. It's a new argument each time, after all. The special thing about an `FnOnce` closure is that calling it will *consume the closure itself*.
2. An `FnMut` closure is allowed to modify *itself* when it is called, i.e. you need at least a mutable borrow of the closure to be able to call it.
3. A function accepting an `FnMut` closure will also accept any `Fn` closure, since all `Fn` closures are implicitly `FnMut`.
4. Your closure is not actually consuming its argument. The argument passed to the closure has type `&i32`, and you use a destructuring pattern to extract an `i32` value `x`. This only works because `i32` implements the `Copy` trait – you actually receive a *copy* of the integer, since it is not allowed to move a value out of a borrow. Dropping a value that is `Copy` does nothing at all – again, only a copy of the value is passed to `drop()`, and `Copy` types can never implement the `Drop` trait.